# Mount Old Synology HDD Drives to a Ubuntu Server Machine

Tags: 14.04, server, mount

I am building a new computer that will replace my 5 year old Synlogy DiskStation NAS. Can I install the WD Red HDDs on the new device without losing my media files? Or does Ubuntu have to convert the drive formats and make new partitions?

> **Old Device:** 213j Synology DiskStation with 2 WD Red 4GBs NAS disks running on DSM OS.
>
> **New Device:** Intel i3-4170 processor, Asrock H97M Pro4 motherboard, 8GB DDR3 RAM, Patriot 60 GB Internal SSD for Ubuntu Server OS.

Running `parted --list`prints on Synology:

```
Warning: Unable to open /dev/hda read-write (Permission denied).  /dev/hda has
been opened read-only.
Model: WDC WD40EFRX-68WT0N0 (scsi)                                        
Disk /dev/hda: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      131kB   2550MB  2550MB  ext4                  raid
 2      2550MB  4698MB  2147MB  linux-swap(v1)        raid
 5      4840MB  4001GB  3996GB                        raid
```

Running `parted --list`prints on Ubuntu Server:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68W (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number Start End Size File system Name Flags
1 131kb 2550MB 2550MB ext4 raid
2 2550MB 4698MB 2147MB linux-swap(u1) raid
5 4840MB 4001GB 3996 GB raid 

Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/vg1000-1v: 39996GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop

Number Start End Size File system Flags
1 0.00B  3996GB 3996GB ext4

Error: /dev/md2/: unrecognized disk label
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Do you have a PC, and you would like to add more HDDs, and the question is, if Ubuntu could mount them? If yes, then I'm pretty sure, that it can - except if you had hardware RAID controlled disks.

Comment: Is that a `parted --list` on the Synology device?

Comment: @fabby No, on my Ubuntu Server machine.

Comment: I need to have the before and after situations, please?  it looks like the Synology is using VGs. Disclaimer: I don't have the same HW as you have...

Comment: @Fabby Ok done.

Comment: Please see me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)?

Answer (score 2):

Although DSM OS is based on Linux, it doesn't use the EXT2/3/4 file system which comes standard with Ubuntu but uses [BTRFS](https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/Btrfs).

Although it [is possible to install BTRFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs) on Ubuntu, it is also:

> ... a new copy on write (CoW) filesystem for Linux aimed at implementing advanced features while focusing on fault tolerance, repair and easy administration and **Btrfs is under heavy development**...

So the short answer is:

#### No, we cannot *guarantee* that plugging the disks from your Synology NAS into an Ubuntu File server will work out-of-the-box.

I would even advise *not to try* before:

1. Making a full image backup using [`dd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dd.1.html)
2. Installing BTRFS:

   ```
    apt-get install btrfs-tools
   ```
3. Installing the disks on the Ubuntu Server in the exact same physical order as they are now installed in the NAS.

### Note:

#### `dd`is also known as *D*isk *D*estroyer so use with care!

Comment: After running `sudo fdisk -l`, it reads:
Disk /dev/md2: 3995.3 GB, 3995938455552 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/tracks, 975570912 cylinders, total 7804567296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096
I/O size (minimum/optional): 4096 bytes /4096 bytes
Disk identifer: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md2 dioesn't contain a valid partitions table

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the info there as it's quite unreadable here.  then delete all of your comments.  (doing this with mine too) I'll be updating my answer...

Answer (score 1):

If you mean adding some HDDs to a desktop PC, then you can do that without any doubts. Ubuntu will auto-mount known file system types, like NTFS, ext4, and much more...

If you need further assistance, ask in comments!

Comment: Yes, I've installed one 4TB HDD from the old Synology NAS with a bunch of media files on it, but Ubuntu 14.04 Server isn't mounting it. How can I find the files on it and make it available on the network to Macs and Windows devices?

Comment: If you connected, please run `sudo fdisk -l`. If you find something like `/dev/sdbX` or `hdbX`, you can mount it. `sudo mkdir -p /media/your_mountpoint; sudo mount /dev/sdbX /media/your_mountpoint`, check with `df -h`